# Limit of definite sum equals $\ln(2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to show the following equality:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=\log(2)$$

I've been playing with it for almost an hour, mainly with the taylor expansion of $\ln(2)$. It looks very similar to what I need, but it has an alternating sign which sits in my way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think $ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\ln{n}+\gamma+c_{n}$,Where $\gamma$ is Euler constant. helps it

Comment: Hint: the sum can be recasted into the form of a Riemann sum $\sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}}^{n} \frac{1}{i} = \frac1n \sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}}^{n}(\frac{i}{n})^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach as pointed out by [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) in [the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326545/limit-of-definite-sum-equals-ln2#comment706119_326545): The limit can be written as a Riemann sum:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=n/2}^n \frac{1}{i} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=n/2}^n \frac{1}{i/n} = \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{dx}{x} = \left.\log x\right|_{1/2}^1 = \log 2
$$

Answer (score 4):

We know the famous relation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log n+\gamma+o(1),$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.
Then we have:
$$\sum_{k=n/2}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\frac{1}{k}=\log n-\log\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)+o(1)=\log\left(\frac{2n}{n-2}\right)+o(1),$$
so it's clear that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n/2}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log 2.$$

Answer (score 4):

Truncate the Maclaurin series for $\log(1+x)$ at the $2m$-th term, and evaluate at $x=1$. Take for example $m=10$. We get 
$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{19}-\frac{1}{20}.$$
Add $2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots +\frac{1}{20}\right)$, and subtract the same thing, but this time noting that
$$ 2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots +\frac{1}{20}\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10}.$$
We get
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\cdots+\frac{1}{20}\right)-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10}\right).$$
There is nice cancellation, and we get
$$\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\cdots+\frac{1}{20}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_2^{n+1} \frac{1}{x-1}\,dx> \sum_2^n \frac{1}{k}>\int_2^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

$$\ln n> \sum_2^n \frac{1}{k}>\ln (n+1)-\ln 2$$

$$\ln n-\ln (n/2)> \sum_{n/2}^n \frac{1}{k}>\ln (n+1)-\ln (n/2+1)$$

$$\ln 2> \sum_{n/2}^n \frac{1}{k}>\ln 2+\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)\to \ln 2$$

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \ln n\to \gamma$$
hence 
$$\sum_{k=\frac n2+1}^n \frac1k -( \ln n -\ln{\frac n2})\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$. (Cf. pxchg1200's comment)